# CMake generates circular dependencies for VS project, but not make files. How to avoid?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, cmake

This sample is boiled down from an actual project I am working on; an MWE of sorts (well, *not* working would be more appropriate).

Consider the following project structure:

```text
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── include
│   └── hello.hpp
└── src
    └── hello.cpp
```

The `build` directory is used to conduct the build and will contain the build artifacts and intermediate files. The contents of the remaining files will be given at the bottom of this question.

The idea is to `install()` the built library along with its header (and some other stuff in the real project).

```cmake
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PRJNAME}
    POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)
```

... along with the `install()` is meant to accomplish this and does for the generators `Unix Makefiles` and `NMake Makefiles`, but creates a circular dependency for `Visual Studio 16 2019` (also for `Visual Studio 14 2015`, but I didn't test any further than that).

Now my immediate reaction was, that this was an inconsistency across generators, but on the other hand the project generation with anything other than make files has been - IMO - one of the weaknesses of CMake all along.

For now my workaround is simply to use the `NMake Makefiles`, but the downside of that approach is that I have to "detect" Visual Studio before and use `vcvarsall.bat`, `vcvars32.bat` and friends. But that's a small nuisance compared to the circular dependency.

How can I use one of the Visual Studio project generators to achieve what I want and dodge that circular dependency?

On Windows I am using **CMake 3.15.1** (latest at the time of writing).

**NB:** I realize that I could use something to the effect of `${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install` by creating custom commands/targets sprinkled with a few `file()` commands. But that wouldn't keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) now, would it?

---

#### `CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
set(CMAKE_RULE_MESSAGES OFF)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)
set(PRJNAME FOOBAR)

project (${PRJNAME})

set(SOURCE_DIR "src")
set(HEADER_DIR "include")
set(TARGET_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/install-target")
set(PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADER_DIR}/hello.hpp")
set(PROJ_SOURCES "${SOURCE_DIR}/hello.cpp")

add_library(${PRJNAME} SHARED ${PROJ_SOURCES})

list(TRANSFORM PUBLIC_HEADER PREPEND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PUBLIC_HEADER_PP)
set_target_properties(
    ${PRJNAME}
    PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 11
        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
        PUBLIC_HEADER "${PUBLIC_HEADER_PP}"
        POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1
)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${TARGET_DIR})
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR lib)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR ${HEADER_DIR})

install(
    TARGETS ${PRJNAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_DIR}")
configure_file("${PUBLIC_HEADER}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_DIR}/" COPYONLY)
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${HEADER_DIR}")

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PRJNAME}
    POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)

set(PKGNAME "foobar-package.zip")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PKGNAME}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar cv "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PKGNAME}" -- .
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${TARGET_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)

set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PKGNAME})

add_custom_target(
    lib
    DEPENDS ${PRJNAME}
)
```

#### `src/hello.cpp`

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE, DWORD, LPVOID) { return TRUE; }
#endif
#include "hello.hpp"

int hello() { return 42; }
```

#### `include/hello.cpp`

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN32
#   ifdef FOOBAR_EXPORTS
#       define FOOBAR_API  __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define FOOBAR_API  __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define FOOBAR_API
#endif

FOOBAR_API int hello();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your use case is beyond what CMake was designed for.
You are trying to build the `INSTALL` target, which in turn builds the `FOOBAR` target, which in turn calls the `INSTALL` command.

If we break the chain here by splitting into two different targets: `FOOBAR` and `FOOBAR_INSTALL` like so

```
add_custom_target(${PRJNAME}_INSTALL ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)
```

we would still get the circular reference through the `ALL_BUILD` target.
So if we remove the `ALL` argument the reference would be broken but the target won't be called from the default build command which is not better than calling `make` and `make install`.

The proper place to break the dependency would be between the `INSTALL` and other targets. Instead of building the `INSTALL` target you can call the generated `cmake_install.cmake` script directly:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PRJNAME}
    POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME=$<CONFIG> -P cmake_install.cmake
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    VERBATIM
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach does indeed break up the dependency cycle and I have adjusted my project and verified that it works.